# Am I able to use Pritunl Wireguard without their client? Where are the connection settings stored?

Tags: wireguard

I installed Pritunl and wireguard packages on my VPS. Then I made WG server settings with [this manual](https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/wireguard).

Now I want to connect to the server but without pritunl client, only using wireguard standard client (to connect from my router for example). Where can I get connection settings/params to do it?

When I use OpenVPN I can just download OpenVPN config file from Pritunl's WebUI, but there is no such files to configure WG.